# what the meaning of this link in linux script

Tags: linux, bash

What is the meaning of the following which is on the top of linux script

```
#!/bin/bash
return &> /dev/null
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The line is to protect users from sourcing the script.

When the script is run (not sourced but run), the script will proceed to the next lines until the end of file.

When the script is sourced, the script will just return and do nothing.

Comment: Interesting. Is this a viable way to prevent users from sourcing a script?

Comment: +1 : Very nice to know. Thanks for that answer, and to the OP for the question! Useful.

Answer (score 5):

`return` is supposed to return value from bash function.

When used exactly like in your example but without `&> /dev/null`, it is invalid use because `return` does not belong to body of bash function, and would print:

```
line 2: return: can only `return' from a function or sourced script
```

However, somebody decided to hide that error message by piping output to `/dev/null`.

In other words, this all does not make much sense.

Comment: Thanks. You have explained functionality of "return" clearly, but @user3088572 explained why it is used on top of some script which is the point of this question.

Answer (score 0):

This discards the unwanted output of your program. Please check out [this link](http://bash.cyberciti.biz/guide//dev/null_discards_unwanted_output), differences between `>`, `2>` and `&>` are very well explained over there.

Quoting:

> command &>/dev/null

*This syntax redirects both standard output and error output messages to /dev/null where it is ignored by the shell.*